# Chrome reloads page during debug PhpStorm/Xdebug

Tags: google-chrome, phpstorm, xdebug

I use Xdebug on my development server and debug using PhpStorm in a page loading in Chrome. However, Chrome has the annoying feature to reload a page if it takes too long to load, launching another debug session on the page I'm already debugging.

I tried looking for a solution, this problem is an oldie, but the solutions posted then aren't applicable anymore.

I tried setting the Max. simultaneous connections to 1, but that causes other windows loading on the same dev server to halt completely until I'm done running the first debug session, so that's not an option for me either.

Is there any way to stop Chrome reloading pages when it 'thinks' the server in question is taking too long to answer?

Comment: Got nothing to say on Chrome part .. but have you considered using another browser for such debug? (e.g. Firefox Developer Edition: https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/developer/)

Comment: Yes, but since it's the most used browser (51.72% vs 8.97% for Firefox) I feel much safer making sure everything works on most browsers. Maybe old-school, and since we try to stay away from browser-specific options it might not effect us, but still...

Comment: PHP and Xdebug don't care about what the browser is. Perhaps use one that isn't a front for an ad-tech company, pushing features on you that are detrimental to your work?

Comment: As I udnerstand your issue is about debugging PHP code and not HTML/CSS/JS. Browser does not matter here (PHP/Xdebug does no care who sent the request): you can send HTTP requests even using cURL/Postman or alike if needs to be. But yes, doing ALL in one browser is more convenient.

Comment: Our PHP generates HTML, the problem is debugging the PHP part, but the output has to work in most browsers. So my initial question remains (since I have a good reason for that to be my preference): is there a way to stop Chrome loading pages when it 'thinks' the server in question is taking too long to answer?

Comment: @patrick I know nothing about such Chrome behaviour. But for me it sounds like Chrome thinks that the internet is down (cos server does not respond for a long time) and it tries to resubmit the request. You said you had some solutions that do not work any more. What they were about? They may contain some keywords on what to search for...

Comment: here's an old stackoverflow question that's technically a duplicate of mine, but the solution there doesn't work anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575695/disable-chrome-auto-reload-on-time-out-error

Comment: I tried debugging with FireFox, but it does the same thing. Worst part is that when the browser reloads the output of the renewed load is shown, hiding any output from the debug session I was working on.

Comment: @patrick I'm using Firefox for PHP debug... and never had such issue. I mean: even if I debug for 10 mins it still works OK for me. For that though I had to configure my web server (increase timeouts) .. otherwise it was killing debug session after 90 seconds (it though that PHP process hanged as it did not made any output in that interval). But even then -- it still shows me the blank page and not reloading the whole page. No ideas about Chrome...

Comment: I'll try that, it could very well be the server that's causing this. Still, even if the server times out it should be reloaded automatically by either firefox or chrome IMO

Comment: @patrick This is what I had to do for local IIS web server (the one that comes with Windows) in order to have longer debug sessions for web pages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489322/783119 NOTE that: I have no guarantee that this info will have any relevance to your case.